# Is there a srcset equivalent to object tag?

Tags: html, css, svg

I like using `srcset` to define responsive images. Supose we have this situation with `picture` and `img`:

```
<picture>
   <source srcset='myimage-large.svg' media='(min-width: 1000px)'>
   <source srcset='myimage-small.svg' media='(min-width: 600px)'>
   <img src='myimage.svg'>
</picture>
```

It works good, but I have to interact with a svg image. So `object` would be the best solution. But how do I do something like `srcset` in this case?

Comment: looks like javascript will be required :( CSS cannot update src attributes )

Comment: @GCyrillus ok, but how do I do that with Javascript?